# Let $f(x)=\tan x$. Examine whether $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, trigonometry, proof-writing

Let $f(x)=\tan x$. Examine whether $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)$ exists.

I tried solving this problem as follows:

We first examine the right-hand limit of $f(x)$ if it at all exists.

The domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R'=\Bbb R-\{2n\pi\pm\pi/2\}.$

We consider $A=\Bbb R'\cap (\pi/2,\infty)=(\pi/2,\infty)-\{2n\pi\pm\pi/2\}$ as the new domain of $f.$ Now, $\pi/2$ is a cluster point of $A$ as well, so that writing $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f$ when the domain taken is $A,$ is meaningful as well.  We claim, that $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f=-\infty$ when domain of $f$ is $A.$

To prove this, we need to show:

$\forall G\in \Bbb R$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that if , $0\lt |x-\pi/2|\lt \delta$ and $x\in A$ we have, $f(x)=\tan x\lt G.$

Indeed if, we take, $\delta=\pi/2+\arctan G,$ then, if $$x\in V_\delta (\pi/2)-\{\pi/2\}\cap A=(\pi/2,\pi+\arctan G),$$ i.e $\pi/2\lt x\lt \pi+\arctan G$ we have, $$\tan x\lt \tan(\pi+\arctan G)=\tan (\arctan G)= G.$$ (This is because, if say, $a<b$ we may say, $\tan a\lt \tan b$ as $f(x)=\tan x$ is an increasing function on $\Bbb R$, because, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\gt 0,\forall x\in\Bbb R.$)

So, we find that, $\forall G\in \Bbb R$ there exists a $\delta=\pi/2+\arctan G,$ such that, if $x\in V_\delta(\pi/2)-\{\pi/2\}\cap A,$ we have, $f(x)\lt G.$

This proves that, if, $f:A\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\tan x$ then, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)=-\infty.$ Thus, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2+}\tan x=-\infty.$

---

We now, consider $$A=\Bbb R'\cap (-\infty,\pi/2)=(-\infty,\pi/2)-\{2n\pi\pm\pi/2\}$$ as the new domain of $f.$ Now, $\pi/2$ is a cluster point of $A$ as well, so that writing $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f$ when the domain taken is $A,$ is meaningful as well.  We claim, that $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f=\infty$ when domain of $f$ is $A.$

To prove this, we need to show:

$\forall G\in \Bbb R$ there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that if , $0\lt |x-\pi/2|\lt \delta$ and $x\in A$ we have, $f(x)=\tan x\gt G.$

Indeed if, we take, $\delta=\pi/2-\arctan G,$ then, if $$x\in V_\delta (\pi/2)-\{\pi/2\}\cap A=(\arctan G,\pi/2),$$ i.e $\arctan G\lt x\lt \pi/2$ we have, $$tan(\arctan G)=G\lt \tan x.$$ (This is because, if say, $a<b$ we may say, $\tan a\lt \tan b$ as $f(x)=\tan x$ is an increasing function on $\Bbb R$, because, $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\gt 0,\forall x\in\Bbb R.$)

So, we find that, $\forall G\in \Bbb R$ there exists a $\delta=\pi/2+\arctan G,$ such that, if $x\in V_\delta(\pi/2)-\{\pi/2\}\cap A,$ we have, $G\lt f(x).$

This proves that, if, $f:A\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=\tan x$ then, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)=\infty.$ Thus, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2-}\tan x=\infty.$

---

Thus, we see that, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2-}\tan x=\infty,$ and
$\lim_{x\to\pi/2+}\tan x=-\infty.$ So, $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\tan x$ does not exist.

---

Now, I want to know, whether the way I have written the proof, needs some improvement or not. Is there any portion in my proof which demands a further clarity? Finally, if something looks awry or if there is some mistake, which needs to be addressed in my proof, please do let me know.

Comment: $~\tan(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}.~$  As $x~ \to \pi/2,~$ the numerator goes to a finite number, and the the denominator goes to $~0.~$ This makes it *game over*.

Comment: @user2661923 But would you consider that rigorous ? I think that is much more an intuitive win than a rigorous win

Comment: Based on my first comment, it is straightforward to construct an $~\epsilon, ~\delta~$ proof by contradiction that the fraction can not have a finite limit.

Comment: @user2661923 Yeah, that might be possible and an alternative way, muly friend. But the thing is, I strongly feel that would be then, a roundabout approach if not a complicated one. The solution in OP seems direct :)

Comment: Re my previous comment, suppose that the fraction has the finite limit $~L~$ and let $~M = |L|.~$  Since the numerator is going to $~1,~$ and the denominator is going to $~0,~$ in any neighborhood around $~\pi/2~$ of radius $~\delta > 0,~$ for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ you can find an element $~x~$ such that $|1 - \sin(x)| < \epsilon~$ and $|0 - \cos(x)| <\epsilon.$  This means that you can find an $~x~$ such that $~\sin(x) \in [1-\epsilon, 1]~$ and $~\cos(x) < \epsilon.~$  So, $~x~$ can be found, for any $~\epsilon~$ such that $~\tan(x) \geq \dfrac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Ah, ok. Though I haven't read it, but the length seems admittedly short. But let's come back to the question of this post and focuss on the proof given, for the sake of mine. Thanks ;)

Comment: Re which approach is straightforward : perhaps it depends on your perspective.  Personally, when I see the numerator going to a finite number, and the denominator going to $~0,~$ I naturally think of the fraction as growing unbounded.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, what you said is true. It all depends on how we see things.

Comment: Unclear to me whether your posting is valid.  Examining the first part of your posting, that focuses on the domain being $~(\pi/2,\infty),~$ you are (in effect) making the assumption that for all $~G \in \Bbb{R^-}, ~\exists ~\theta,~$ such that $~\tan(\theta) = G.~$  While this is true, as $~G~$ goes to $~-\infty,~$ you will have to approach very close to $~\pi/2~$ to find a satisfactory $~\theta.~$  It is unclear to me whether you are *assuming what you are trying to prove*, namely that the absolute value of $~\tan(x)~$ grows unbounded, as $~x \to \pi/2.$

Comment: Note: the statement at the beginning that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ is false. The function is not defined at odd multiples of $\pi/2$, as you know, since $\cos x = 0$ at those places.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed it.

Comment: Assuming some basic properties of limits, if the limit existed then you would have $1 = \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \sin x  = (\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \cos x) (\lim_{x \to \pi/2} \tan x) = 0 \times (\dots)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @ronno Wow! That's an elegant one